# Lost funds on my lightning node?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

I've been using lightning network daemon (LND). In an effort to have a balanced node with somewhat equal amounts on both side of my channels, I've sometimes opened channels with the command `lncli openchannel Xdest_nodeXX local-amt push-amt` and specify push-amt to be approximately 50% of the local-amt. Over the last year or so I've opened and subsequently closed numerous channels in this way. [This discussion on stackexchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/76983/when-opening-a-ln-channel-using-lnd-what-does-push-amt-do) indicates the funds are irretrievably send to the other node and my funds are lost! Is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Unfortunately this is true. Using push-amt means that you send over an amount to the other side wich they own. While it takes place offhand it is final in a similar way as sending Bitcoin to an address.

The only way I see to get your funds back is if you talk to the owners of the nodes you opened channels with explain them the situation and ask to get reimbursed.

Comment: F*!$& idiotic, particularly that there isn't better documentation to that effect. People need to be informed of this.